# Save a column of date format with Numpy

Tags: date, numpy, datetime

I am trying to save a text file with a date column using the following Python code. I encounter the following error message when I run the last line:

"is {IndexError}tuple index out of range"

```
import numpy as np

dt = np.datetime64('%4d-%02d-%02d' % (2018,2,9))
names = ['date']
formats = ['datetime64[us]']
dtype = dict(names=names, formats=formats)
column = np.array(dt, dtype)
np.savetxt('date_series.csv', column, delimiter=',', header='date')
```

What index is the error message referring to? How should the code be corrected?

Comment: `column` is a 0d array.  `savetxt` saves a 1d array as a column, a 2d array as rows of columns.  version 1.14 has a different error message: `Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [263]: np.savetxt('test',column)
....
ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead
```

change to saving a 1d array:

```
In [264]: np.savetxt('test',[column])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'


TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('[('date', '<M8[us]')]') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

Works with a generic %s format:

```
In [265]: np.savetxt('test',[column], fmt='%s')
In [266]: cat test
2018-02-09T00:00:00.000000
```

A 2d array of times:

```
In [271]: times = np.arange(np.datetime64('2018-02-09'),np.datetime64('2018-02-27'))
In [272]: times = times.reshape(3,-1)
In [273]: np.savetxt('test',times, fmt='%s')
In [274]: cat test
2018-02-09 2018-02-10 2018-02-11 2018-02-12 2018-02-13 2018-02-14
2018-02-15 2018-02-16 2018-02-17 2018-02-18 2018-02-19 2018-02-20
2018-02-21 2018-02-22 2018-02-23 2018-02-24 2018-02-25 2018-02-26
```

---

Fields of a 1d structured array will be treated as columns:

```
In [288]: dt=np.dtype('<M8[D],<M8[D],<M8[D]')
In [290]: arr = np.array([tuple(x) for x in times.T.tolist()],dt)
In [291]: np.savetxt('test',arr,fmt='%s')
In [292]: cat test
2018-02-09 2018-02-15 2018-02-21
2018-02-10 2018-02-16 2018-02-22
2018-02-11 2018-02-17 2018-02-23
2018-02-12 2018-02-18 2018-02-24
2018-02-13 2018-02-19 2018-02-25
2018-02-14 2018-02-20 2018-02-26

In [296]: np.savetxt('test',arr,fmt='%s, %10s; %20s')
In [297]: cat test
2018-02-09, 2018-02-15;           2018-02-21
2018-02-10, 2018-02-16;           2018-02-22
...
```

Comment: Thank you. But what do I do if I want to keep the structured array format np.array(dt,dtype)?

Comment: What do you mean by sturctured array format?  The ()?

Comment: In my specific example, I mean I would like to use the format column = np.array(dt, dtype), where dtype specifies the data type.

Comment: I see you have edited your answer. +1 Let me try it out tomorrow then accept your answer afterwards. Thank you.